# Universal Analytics Tag not fired in GTM

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am newbie in GTM and being headache with Universal Analytics firing.  I followed [this step by step](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/ua#send-events) tutorial but never got any event on my Google Analytics. Please point me my mistake if any.  Here is how I configured:

1. Config UA id and Event parameters:
   `{{Event Category}}` `{{Event Action}}` `{{Event Label}}` `{{Event Value}}` are variables I created
   [image]

Here is how I configured for `{{Event Category}}`. Other's configuration are same.

[image]

2. setup "fields to set" setting: 
   `{{App Name}}` `{{App Version Code}}` are predefined variables.
   [image]
3. Event trigger setting:
   [image]

[image]

4. Finally, here is how I push event to datalayer:

   - Initialize at splash screen activity. `test_v8` is the binary file I download from GTM.

>

```
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID,
                    R.raw.test_v8);
    // The onResult method will be called as soon as one of the following happens:
    //1. a saved container is loaded
    //2. if there is no saved container, a network container is loaded
    //3. the request times out. The example below uses a constant to manage the timeout period.
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
        }
    }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    launchApplication();
}
```

- Push event when user click button:

> ```
>  dataLayer.pushEvent("action", DataLayer.mapOf("category", "test category", "action", "test action", "label", "test label"));
> ```

Update: I use GTM V4 for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by remove `{{Event Value}}` configuration. Leave that field empty and GTM works like a charm.